# Prove that a specific fixed point iteration is locally convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, newton-raphson

Let $g : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ map such that $g'(x) \ne 0$ for any $x$ in $I$. Assume that there exists $r \in I$ such that $g(r)=0$. Prove that for $\eta \in I$ sufficiently close to $r$ then the fixed point iteration 
$$x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{g(x_k)}{g'(x_k)},\,x_0=\eta$$
satisfies $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}x_k=r$.

I noticed that this is Newton's method for finding the roots of $g$, but I couldn't manage yet to prove the desired conclusion.

Comment: Retagged: there is no differential equation and no initial-value problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Just write
$$
x_{k+1}-r=x_k-r-\frac{g(r)+g'(\tilde x_k)(x_k-r)}{g'(x_k)}
$$
so that
$$
|x_{k+1}-r|\le\frac{M-m}{m}|x_k-r|
$$
where $M=\max_{x\in[r-c,r+c]}|g'(x)|$ and $m=\min_{x\in[r-c,r+c]}|g'(x)|$. Obviously, $M-m\to 0$ for $c\to 0$.